# Possible inconsistency of column representation with orthogonality of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let's say I have two vectors $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ which form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. Any vector $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be represented as $$v = av_{1} + bv_{2}$$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Following the tenet of column representation of vectors, in the basis $\{v_{1}, v_{2}\}$, the representation of $v$ is 
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
         a\\
         b\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

This implies that the representation of $v_{1}$ is $
        \begin{pmatrix}
         1\\
         0\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$ and that of $v_{2}$ is $
        \begin{pmatrix}
         0\\
         1\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$ i.e. the representations are orthogonal but the original vectors $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ **may not necessarily be so**. This gives rise to a lot of problems like how to normalise and stuff.

I know this is silly but what is wrong with my argument?

Comment: can you be more specific about the "a lot of problems like how to normalise and stuff". what's the problem with $v1 = (1,1), v2 = (1,0)$

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think that in this new basis, the usual scalar product can be computed using  the component-wise multiplication with the old coordinates?

Actually, if $u =a  v_1 +b v_2 $ and $ v =c v_1 + d v_2 $ then:
$$\langle u,v \rangle = ac \langle v_1,v_1 \rangle + bd \langle v_2,v_2 \rangle + (ad+bc)\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle$$
So the formula $ac+bd$ works only if $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is an orthonormal basis.

However, if you define a new scalar product by $\langle u,v \rangle_\text{new} = u^T Q^T Q v $ (instead of $\langle u,v \rangle = u^T v $ for the usual scalar product) with $Q$ the matrix of change of basis from $\{e_1,e_2\}$ to $\{v_1,v_2\}$, then you will have $\langle u,v \rangle_\text{new} = ac+bd $ and $\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle_\text{new}$ will be equal to zero as you expected.